# fetch individual layer blobs from azure CR using API v2

Tags: azure, docker, authentication, layer, docker-registry

I'm trying to re-implement `docker pull` for Azure registries. I've successfully done so in the past against Docker Hub following the official documentation.

For Azure, I manage to list repositories tags via `_catalog` and fetch manifests (`/manifests`), however I'm hitting authentication issues against `/blobs`, where I receive:

`<Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code><Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.`

My code is similar to:

```
    const headers: any = {
      Accept: mediaType
    };
    const config: any = {
      method: "GET",
      uri: `https://${registryConfig.base}/v2/${repo}/blobs/${sha}`,
      headers
    };

    if (token) {
      headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    } else {
      config.auth = { username, password };
    }
    return request(config)
  }
```

This works well for Docker Hub where I'm using a bearer token. Any hints on how to properly authenticate against Azure's blob service?

Thanks!

Comment: For the sake of argument, I've tried via a Bearer token I've acquired; the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to automatic redirects (and some unexpected/non-documented behaviour on Azure's part).

Calls against the `/blobs` endpoint (if they are properly authenticated) include a `Location` header that consists of a different URI that holds the required blob.

However, if you try to call it WITH the autherization header, it fails with the aforementioned error.